# google visualization orgchart same name for two child not showing

Tags: php, json, charts, google-visualization, visualization

When assigning two sub names (Same name) for same superior displays only one sub level. How can i Solve this?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["orgchart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
        data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

        data.addRows([
          [{v:'Mike', f:'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'}, '', 'The President'],
          [{v:'Jim', f:'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President<div>'}, 'Mike', 'VP'],
          ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
          ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
          ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
          ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
      }
   </script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div""></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle Link:](http://jsfiddle.net/kb24mcp1/) http://jsfiddle.net/kb24mcp1/

In the above example **Mike** is the first level and **Alice** is the first child of **MIKE** when i add another child for **MIKE** with the same name as **ALICE** it s not showing. How can Solve this issue?

Comment: Not sure why would you need that, but you can use: `{v:'randomString', f:'Alice'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt find a Great answer but It worked for me. given a space for the second name and it worked.

i.e

```
data.addRows([
          [{v:'Mike', f:'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'}, '', 'The President'],
          [{v:'Jim', f:'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President<div>'}, 'Mike', 'VP'],
          ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
          ['Alice ', 'Mike', ''],
          ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
          ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
        ]);
```

For the second 'Alice ' after the name I given a space. Which worked.